# mat-slider showing negative values with initial value 0 without track fill

Tags: angularjs, mat-slider

What I tried :

```
<mat-slider min="-100" max="100" step="1" value="0"></mat-slider>
```

Here Zero is showing middle with track fill up to Zero but I want to display intial Zero without track fill and also when I select any negative value track should fill from zero

Can any one help me how to do this....